# Is there a way to pass string value to js file from View via function

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass Model values from View to js via function. The problem is, i can pass integer, double values but not string. Is there a way to pass string to js via function?

Passing (cshtml file):

```
ng-submit="vm.updateProduct(@Model.Id, @Model.Name, @Model.Price)"
```

Receiving (js file):

```
vm.updateProduct = function (id, productName, productPrice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add quotes around the string parameter. `@Model.Name` will only render the string value, so you need the quotes to make it valid javascript:

```
ng-submit="vm.updateProduct(@Model.Id, '@Model.Name', @Model.Price)"
```